# use of tuples in C# 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, tuples

Can i replace the following with a tuple and a list. Will there be any dip in performance or what is the best alternative.

```
1. Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, User>>
```

Can I change this to the following

```
2. Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, Address>> userdata
```

Kindly suggest.
Note: There seems to be no way to group tuples, so i think that 2 may be better be replaced by 1.

Comment: Of course you can group tuples if they are in a List - use LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuple will hold exactly one pair of values. Dictionary will hold an arbitraty number of such pairs. So of course 1 and 2 are not equivalent - one holds a collection of collections of pairs, another just a collection of pairs.

slugster is correct: you can group a list of tuples using linq [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) method.